# Possible to tell if two objects are the same in Chrome debugger?

Tags: javascript, debugging, object, google-chrome-devtools

In Eclipse, the debugger shows a unique session id next to each object (for Java and AS3, anyway). This makes it simple to identify the same object appearing in multiple contexts.

I'm working on a JavaScript project, and would like the same ability to identify objects in the Chrome debugger (e.g. in the "Scope Variables" pane). Is this information tracked by the browser/debugger? Is there a different way to identify an object across contexts, without adding code (a purely IDE way of doing this, applicable to any context).

Comment: Per @beefeather's answer, I filed a Chromium feature request: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=263116

Answer (score 2):

Technically this is possible. You probably already can see it, if you use
Chrome Dev Tools for Java (Eclipse-based debugger). 
http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools

As to in-browser debugger, UI merely lacks UI for this. I guess you should file a feature request on this at:
http://crbug.com

P.S. Note, that this not an address at all – both Java and JavaScript move their objects in memory at random moments.

Comment: Based on some googling, it seems you're correct about the id in the Eclipse debugger not being a memory address.  I'll edit my question, though the basic premise remains....and thanks for the Chromium feature/bug report link.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript does not have memory addresses. "The same variable" can be compared using the triple equal sign notation (`anObjectReference === anotherObjectReference`)

Comment: the objects have to be stored in memory somewhere.  whether or not Chrome debugger has access to the VM's memory addresses is another question.

Comment: The `===` operator does not compare identity but values and types.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost if the type or value is different then the identity will be different too.  Otherwise: (quoting MDN) *For all values except numbers, it uses the obvious semantics: a value is only equal to itself*.  So for objects it can definitely be used to check for identity equality.

Comment: @ericsoco I think the statement "*JavaScript does not have memory addresses*" is entirely correct since JavaScript is a language and there is no concept of memory addresses in that language.

Comment: There is always confusion around this. For objects, == and ===, do the same thing. "If both operands are objects, then JavaScript compares internal references which are equal when operands refer to the same object in memory" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is possible using Chrome Dev Tools by:

1. Taking a Heap Snapshot and opening up console while in summary view
2. Printing the object in the console
3. Right clicking the console output and selecting "Reveal in Summary View" (If you don't see this option it is likely that you do not have the profile panel open)

Comment: Tried but doesn't work for Chrome 94